# How do I test for non-nullness of a property in Chai-as-Promised

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

How do I test that an object retrieved from a fulfilled promise has a non-null property?

I have a promise that returns an object similar to the following:

```
{
    id: 1,
    aDate: 2015-02-12T11:50:00.511Z
}
```

I need to check that the `aDate` property is set and non null. How do I check for the existence of the `aDate` property without knowing its exact value (preferably using `.should.eventually. ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more assertion to the property with **and**

```
promise.should.eventually.have.property('aDate').and.not.to.be.null;
```

Comment: Thank you! That does exactly what I wanted. I guess that was just too intuitive for me to realize to try. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
return promise.then(function(obj) {
   assert(obj.aDate != null);
});
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use an approach more 'chai-as-promised -like' so that I don't have to actually interact with the promise myself (as in promise.should.eventually.have.property('aDate'), which incidentally doesn't account for the non-nullness).